# How can I write a long equation in multi line scaled to text width?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, scaling

I want to write a long equation over several lines, but result looks highly irregular.

How can write this equation better, preferably with all equation occupying the same wide?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[]{breqn}‎

\usepackage{lipsum}‎
\begin{document}‎
How can I write equation beatifull. I want all equation the same of text width‎
\lipsum[1]
‎\begin{equation*}‎
‎\begin{split}‎
‎&+\left[ {{T}_{44}}\left( 1,2 \right) \right.+2{{T}_{44}}\left( 5,2 \right)+\left‎. ‎{{T}_{44}}\left( 2,2 \right) \right]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\eta }^{4}}}+\left[ {{T}_{44}}\left( 1,3 \right) \right.+2{{T}_{44}}\left( 5,3 \right)\\‎
‎&+\left‎. ‎{{T}_{44}}\left( 2,3 \right) \right]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{3}}\partial \eta }+\left[ {{T}_{44}}\left( 1,4 \right)+2{{T}_{44}}\left( 5,4 \right)+{{T}_{44}}\left( 2,4 \right) \right]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial \xi \partial {{\eta }^{3}}}\\‎
‎&+\left[ {{T}_{44}}\left( 1,5 \right)+2{{T}_{44}}\left( 5,5 \right)+{{T}_{44}}\left( 2,5 \right) \right]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{2}}\partial {{\eta }^{2}}}+\left[ {{T}_{43}}\left( 1,1 \right) \right.+2{{T}_{43}}\left( 5,1 \right)\\‎
‎&+\left‎. ‎{{T}_{43}}\left( 2,1 \right) \right]\frac{{{\partial }^{3}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{3}}}+\left[ {{T}_{43}}\left( 1,2 \right)+2{{T}_{43}}\left( 5,2 \right)+{{T}_{43}}\left( 2,2 \right) \right]\frac{{{\partial }^{3}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\eta }^{3}}}\\‎
&+\left[ {{T}_{43}}\left( 1,3 \right)+2{{T}_{43}}\left( 5,3 \right)+{{T}_{43}}\left( 2,3 \right) \right]\frac{{{\partial }^{3}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{2}}\partial \eta }++\left[ {{T}_{43}}\left( 1,4 \right) \right.+2{{T}_{43}}\left( 5,4 \right)\\‎
&+\left. ‎{{T}_{43}}\left( 2,4 \right) \right]\frac{{{\partial }^{3}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial \xi \partial {{\eta }^{2}}}+\left( {{T}_{42}}\left( 1,1 \right)+2{{T}_{42}}\left( 5,1 \right)+{{T}_{42}}\left( 2,1 \right) \right)\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{2}}}\\‎ 
&‎+\left[ {{T}_{42}}\left( 1,2 \right)+2{{T}_{42}}\left( 5,2 \right)+{{T}_{42}}\left( 2,2 \right) \right]\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\eta }^{2}}}+\left[ {{T}_{42}}\left( 1,3 \right)‎+ ‎\right.2{{T}_{42}}\left( 5,3 \right)\\‎
&\left. +‎{{T}_{42}}\left( 2,3 \right) \right]\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial \xi \partial \eta }+\left[ {{T}_{41}}\left( 1,1 \right)+2{{T}_{41}}\left( 5,1 \right)+{{T}_{41}}\left( 2,1 \right) \right]\frac{\partial {{w}^{b}}}{\partial \xi }\\‎
&\left. +‎\left[ {{T}_{41}}\left( 1,1 \right)+2{{T}_{41}}\left( 5,1 \right)+{{T}_{41}}\left( 2,1 \right) \right]\frac{\partial {{w}^{b}}}{\partial \eta } \right\}-2\mu {{\tau }^{s}}\left\{ \left[ {{T}_{44}}\left( 1,1 \right)‎+ ‎\right.2{{T}_{44}}\left( 5,1 \right) \right.\\‎
&+\left. ‎{{T}_{44}}\left( 2,1 \right) \right]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{4}}}+\left[ {{T}_{44}}\left( 1,2 \right) \right.+2{{T}_{44}}\left( 5,2 \right)+\left‎. ‎{{T}_{44}}\left( 2,2 \right) \right]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{s}}}{\partial {{\eta }^{4}}}+\left[ {{T}_{44}}\left( 1,3 \right) \right.‎‎
‎\end{split}‎‎‎
\end{equation*}‎

\end{document}
```

Here is an example output of the code above:

[image]

Comment: I see that neither voted nor accepted any answers to your previous questions. Please consider marking them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

Comment: One possibility would be to use `align` instead and put a `&` before every `+`. Maybe the alignment could be misleading, but at least it will look much more regular.

Comment: I think you should think hard again about the structure of your formula. Almost all the linebreaks are inside some brace structure. Do examples from literature also look like this?? Maybe some sort of matrix notation would be easier to read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a lot of mis matched brackets `(` and `[` and `{` which makes the source and the output hard to follow. I assumed that they were intended to be matched and let Tex find the line breaks on its own:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}‎
How can I write equation beatifull. I want all equation the same of text width‎
\lipsum[1]

‎\begin{center}
‎$\displaystyle
{[ {{T}_{44}}( 1,2 ) +2{{T}_{44}}( 5,2 )+‎{{T}_{44}}( 2,2 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\eta }^{4}}}}+
{[ {{T}_{44}}( 1,3 ) +2{{T}_{44}}( 5,3 )‎‎+‎{{T}_{44}}( 2,3 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{3}}\partial \eta }}+
{[ {{T}_{44}}( 1,4 )+2{{T}_{44}}( 5,4 )+{{T}_{44}}( 2,4 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial \xi \partial {{\eta }^{3}}}}‎+
{[ {{T}_{44}}( 1,5 )+2{{T}_{44}}( 5,5 )+{{T}_{44}}( 2,5 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{2}}\partial {{\eta }^{2}}}}+
{[ {{T}_{43}}( 1,1 ) +2{{T}_{43}}( 5,1 )‎+‎{{T}_{43}}( 2,1 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{3}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{3}}}}+
{[ {{T}_{43}}( 1,2 )+2{{T}_{43}}( 5,2 )+{{T}_{43}}( 2,2 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{3}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\eta }^{3}}}}‎+
{[ {{T}_{43}}( 1,3 )+2{{T}_{43}}( 5,3 )+{{T}_{43}}( 2,3 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{3}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{2}}\partial \eta }}+ 
{[ {{T}_{43}}( 1,4 ) +2{{T}_{43}}( 5,4 )‎+ ‎{{T}_{43}}( 2,4 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{3}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial \xi \partial {{\eta }^{2}}}}+
{[ {{T}_{42}}( 1,1 )+2{{T}_{42}}( 5,1 )+{{T}_{42}}( 2,1 ) )\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{2}}}}‎+
{[ {{T}_{42}}( 1,2 )+2{{T}_{42}}( 5,2 )+{{T}_{42}}( 2,2 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\eta }^{2}}}}+
{[ {{T}_{42}}( 1,3 )‎+ ‎2{{T}_{42}}( 5,3 )‎ +‎{{T}_{42}}( 2,3 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial \xi \partial \eta }}+
{[ {{T}_{41}}( 1,1 )+2{{T}_{41}}( 5,1 )+{{T}_{41}}( 2,1 ) ]\frac{\partial {{w}^{b}}}{\partial \xi }}‎ +‎
{[ {{T}_{41}}( 1,1 )+2{{T}_{41}}( 5,1 )+{{T}_{41}}( 2,1 ) ]\frac{\partial {{w}^{b}}}{\partial \eta } -2\mu {{\tau }^{s}}}+
{[ {{T}_{44}}( 1,1 )‎+ ‎2{{T}_{44}}( 5,1 ) ‎+ ‎{{T}_{44}}( 2,1 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{4}}}}+
{[ {{T}_{44}}( 1,2 ) +2{{T}_{44}}( 5,2 ) +‎{{T}_{44}}( 2,2 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{s}}}{\partial {{\eta }^{4}}}}+
   {{T}_{44}}( 1,3 )
$\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Or using `breqn` essentially the same input produces

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{breqn}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}‎
How can I write equation beatifull. I want all equation the same of text width‎
\lipsum[1]

\begin{dmath*}
{[ {{T}_{44}}( 1,2 ) +2{{T}_{44}}( 5,2 )+‎{{T}_{44}}( 2,2 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\eta }^{4}}}}+
{[ {{T}_{44}}( 1,3 ) +2{{T}_{44}}( 5,3 )‎‎+‎{{T}_{44}}( 2,3 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{3}}\partial \eta }}+
{[ {{T}_{44}}( 1,4 )+2{{T}_{44}}( 5,4 )+{{T}_{44}}( 2,4 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial \xi \partial {{\eta }^{3}}}}‎+
{[ {{T}_{44}}( 1,5 )+2{{T}_{44}}( 5,5 )+{{T}_{44}}( 2,5 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{2}}\partial {{\eta }^{2}}}}+
{[ {{T}_{43}}( 1,1 ) +2{{T}_{43}}( 5,1 )‎+‎{{T}_{43}}( 2,1 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{3}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{3}}}}+
{[ {{T}_{43}}( 1,2 )+2{{T}_{43}}( 5,2 )+{{T}_{43}}( 2,2 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{3}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\eta }^{3}}}}‎+
{[ {{T}_{43}}( 1,3 )+2{{T}_{43}}( 5,3 )+{{T}_{43}}( 2,3 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{3}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{2}}\partial \eta }}+ 
{[ {{T}_{43}}( 1,4 ) +2{{T}_{43}}( 5,4 )‎+ ‎{{T}_{43}}( 2,4 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{3}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial \xi \partial {{\eta }^{2}}}}+
{[ {{T}_{42}}( 1,1 )+2{{T}_{42}}( 5,1 )+{{T}_{42}}( 2,1 ) )\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{2}}}}‎+
{[ {{T}_{42}}( 1,2 )+2{{T}_{42}}( 5,2 )+{{T}_{42}}( 2,2 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\eta }^{2}}}}+
{[ {{T}_{42}}( 1,3 )‎+ ‎2{{T}_{42}}( 5,3 )‎ +‎{{T}_{42}}( 2,3 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{2}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial \xi \partial \eta }}+
{[ {{T}_{41}}( 1,1 )+2{{T}_{41}}( 5,1 )+{{T}_{41}}( 2,1 ) ]\frac{\partial {{w}^{b}}}{\partial \xi }}‎ +‎
{[ {{T}_{41}}( 1,1 )+2{{T}_{41}}( 5,1 )+{{T}_{41}}( 2,1 ) ]\frac{\partial {{w}^{b}}}{\partial \eta } -2\mu {{\tau }^{s}}}+
{[ {{T}_{44}}( 1,1 )‎+ ‎2{{T}_{44}}( 5,1 ) ‎+ ‎{{T}_{44}}( 2,1 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{b}}}{\partial {{\xi }^{4}}}}+
{[ {{T}_{44}}( 1,2 ) +2{{T}_{44}}( 5,2 ) +‎{{T}_{44}}( 2,2 ) ]\frac{{{\partial }^{4}}{{w}^{s}}}{\partial {{\eta }^{4}}}}+
   {{T}_{44}}( 1,3 )
\end{dmath*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Which contradicts the standard convension that in displayed math, the break should come before the `+` not after it

Comment: @daleif, breqn alternative shown